# LAN8720 MDC (SMI Clock) and/or ringing issue

Tags: ethernet, phy, lan8720

I had always difficult times with designs having LAN8720 device on it. It behaves differently with each design (this is understandable and even I carefully design it according to the design recommendations).

I have two designs. One is working great, exactly the same schematic, same software on the host microcontroller. Only differences are the number of layers and the size of the boards.

I also suspect a possible ringing somewhere.I have already tried to set some 12pF cap on the various RMII lines but not helped.

Here are some scope extracts from the both designs.

**The one works normal:**

**REFCLK0**

[image]

**MDC**

[image]

**The one fails:**
Note that: Both LED1 and LED2 are blinking at the same time every 2-3 seconds, 5 times and stopping for 10 seconds and starting again. This must be saying something about the issue but there is no information about how to interpret LED blinkings other than as an indicator of speed and activity.

**REFCLK0**

[image]

**MDC**

This should not be a correct signal. At least it should be clocking in 4.29 MHz.

[image]

**This is the schematic I use with my both design:**

[image]

I am out of options about what to check more. Any opinions
regarding the issue is greatly appreciated.